# Can we stop JMeter load test Auto stop

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm executing the JMeter load test with 5 users, 1 hours duration. If my 5 users operations will be completed in below 1 hours, Can it stop automatically. Do we have any option like this?

Answer (score 0):

Just untick this `Specify Thread lifetime` box under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

[image]

and once last of your 5 threads (users) will finish executing its last [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) your test will end

You can also untick the `Infinite` box next to the "Loop Count" and your test will stop after completing all the iterations or after 3600 seconds, whatever comes the first:

[image]

See [Getting Started with JMeter - A Basic Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial) for essential information on how to build your first web test plan with JMeter